# Include header file causes compilation error when added to a specific class

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a problem with the following project structure. It does not want to compile properly.

```
\apps
  |____ \app1
  |        |____ App1.cpp, App1.h
  |        |____ CMakeLists.txt
  |                
  |____ \src
          |____ \lib_a
                   |____ \include : Class_a.h
                   |____ Class_a.cpp
                   |____ CMakeLists.txt
                \lib_b
                   |____ \include : Class_b.h
                   |____ Class_b.cpp
                   |____ CMakeLists.txt
                \lib_c
                   |____ \include : Class_c.h, Class_data1c.h, Class_data2c.h
                   |____ Class_c.cpp, Class_data1c.cpp, Class_data2c.cpp
                   |____ CMakeLists.txt
```

Where:

.\app1\CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(app1 "App1.cpp" "App1.h")
target_compile_features(app1 PRIVATE cxx_std_11)

target_link_libraries(app1 PRIVATE lib_a)
target_link_libraries(app1 PRIVATE lib_b)
target_link_libraries(app1 PRIVATE lib_c)
```

.\src\lib_a\CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(LIBA_SRC "Class_a.cpp")
set(LIBA_H "./include/Class_a.h")

add_library(lib_a ${LIBA_SRC} ${LIBA_H})

target_include_directories(lib_a PUBLIC "include")
target_link_libraries(lib_a PRIVATE lib_b lib_c)

target_compile_features(lib_a PUBLIC cxx_std_11)

source_group(
  TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  PREFIX "Header Files"
  FILES ${LIBA_H})
```

.\src\lib_b\CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(LIBB_SRC "Class_b.cpp")
set(LIBB_H "./include/Class_b.h")

add_library(lib_b ${LIBB_SRC} ${LIBB_H})

target_include_directories(lib_b PUBLIC "include")
target_link_libraries(lib_b PRIVATE lib_a lib_c)

target_compile_features(lib_b PUBLIC cxx_std_11)

source_group(
  TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  PREFIX "Header Files"
  FILES ${LIBB_H})
```

.\src\lib_c\CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(LIBC_SRC "Class_c.cpp" "Class_data1c.cpp" "Class_data2c.cpp")
set(LIBC_H "./include/Class_c.h" "./include/Class_data1c.h" "./include/Class_data2c.h")

add_library(lib_c ${LIBC_SRC} ${LIBC_H})

target_include_directories(lib_c PUBLIC "include")
target_link_libraries(lib_c PRIVATE lib_a lib_b)

target_compile_features(lib_c PUBLIC cxx_std_11)

source_group(
  TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  PREFIX "Header Files"
  FILES ${LIBC_H})
```

The definition for the classes are the following (in each own file):

```
#include "Class_b.h"
#include "Class_c.h"
class Class_a{
    Class_a();
    void func1(class_b::enum_type n);
    void func2(class_c::enum_type n);
}

#include "Class_a.h"
#include "Class_c.h"
class Class_b{
    Class_b();
    void func1(class_a::enum_type n);
    void func2(class_c::enum_type n);
    
    Class_c obj_b;
}

#include "Class_a.h"
#include "Class_b.h"
#include "Class_data1c.h"
class Class_c{
    Class_b();
    void func1(class_a::enum_type n);
    void func2(class_b::enum_type n);
    
    Class_data1c data1;
}

#include "Class_data2c.h"
class Class_data1c{
    Class_data1c();
    
    Class_data2c data2;
}
```

The problem is that if I include the Class_c header in Class_b, then I get the error that Class_c is not found. If I remove it, then everything compiles and runs.
I think there is something wrong with the CMAKE definition files and/or the project structure.
Can you please help me to understand what is wrong with this project?

Comment: How do you expect `class_a` to include `class_b`  and `class_b` to included `class_a`? Do you not see an endless loop/dependency here?

Comment: Yes noticed it :(. Sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have dependency loop: class_a includes class_b, class_b includes class_a and so on.
To avoid this problem, you can use defender in all your hedar files that will avoid this loop:

```
#ifndef    YOUR_NAMESPACE_YOUR_FILENAME_H
#define    YOUR_NAMESPACE_YOUR_FILENAME_H

#include //all your includes

class MyClass {
    //content of your class
}


#endif //YOUR_NAMESPACE_YOUR_FILENAME_H
```